I am unable to change the font-weight or width of a @font-face in CSS
I downloaded a variable font that supports changes to weight and width, but when I attempt to change the weight or width of the font it does not change. However, when I utilize a link to import the font instead of using the .ttf file, changing the font-weight works.
I have tried to use font-variation-settings as well as font-weight but it does not seem to work.
Here is my code for @font-face and the header in a div class where the font is being applied:
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Archivo';
    src: url(fonts/Archivo-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf) format('truetype');
}

.front .name{
    font-family: 'Archivo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 4.5vw;
    font-variation-settings:"wght" 1000, "wdth" 100;
    color: rgb(255,222,90);
}

The link I used in my html document that applied the font:
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


Can you show us the link you are using which works [it sounds as though that loads more variants].

The @font-face rule should work flawlessly - provided the font url is correct. The path/url needs to be relative to the final CSS location. E.g If you're using a preprocessor like scss the font url needs to be relative to the compiled CSS output file - not the original .scss file (which may reside in a module subdirectory). Check the dev tools network tab if the font is loaded

Thanks for adding the link. Without knowing what your .ttf file contains it's difficult to be certain, but I imagine that's just got the default copy of the font, not the wght variants which you are loading with the link. See https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#:~:text=The%20Google%20Fonts%20API%20provides%20the%20regular%20version,weights%20separated%20by%20commas%20%28%2C%29.%20For%20example%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Ffonts.googleapis.com%2Fcss%3Ffamily%3DTangerine%3Abold%2Cbolditalic%7CInconsolata%3Aitalic%7CDroid%2BSans

Archivo-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf should actually be the complete (un-subset) font file including all variable axes. Apart from the aforementioned URL/path you may also check your dev tools console for any OTS parsing errors. These errors relate to font file corruption that can happen during uploads or incorrect trnasfer/processing config settings when using a bundler like web-pack.

@herrstrietzel yes, the problem is we don’t know how that file has been created.

@A Haworth: actually we don't know if it was recompiled or converted e.g via a bundling process, upload or font-converter. By it's name "Archivo-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf" (matching the original file name you get when downloading  Archivo as zip from the google font UI) it should be the working VF version (otherwise you won't get a .ttf file). So the OP should clarify if any post-processing was applied to the font file and check the local file URLs/paths. It's more likely a URL/path issue.

The comma in the URL looks wrong.

@kmoser That's the syntax used by Google Fonts. For example. the "embed" link for Roboto: <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

@TiesonT. Commas, if they appear in a URL at all, are generally part of the query string, i.e. the part after the "?" It's unorthodox for them to be part of the URL path or filename, which is why the URL in the OP looks suspect.

@TiesonT. note that in the Google Fonts syntax the comma and subsequnt text are part of a query string (ie after a ?) - in the question the URL has them as part of the URL which is not something I've seen before. I would be surprised if that URL yields anything.

@AHaworth Thanks, but I'm aware of how query strings work, and there's nothing wrong with those commas in the original URL or the example I gave. Google Fonts knows how to parse that family=... parameter to something meaningful, so that's not the issue here

I don’t see where google fonts being able to parse fonts/Archivo-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf comes into it. You are asking your browser to use that url as a src and it doesn’t look like a proper url to me. Are you certain it is downloadable, has your browser found it?1

@AHaworth I think we're looking at two different things. I was focused on the last bit in the question, where the OP has the Google Fonts embed code (the <link ... bits). I assume that you're referencing the src: url(fonts/Archivo-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf) in the @font-face declaration?

@TiesonT. yes, its looks like an incorrect URL and I don't understand why OP thinks it correct.

@AHaworth Interestingly, it is correct. I just downloaded the "self host" bundle for the Archivo font, and that's the actual file name in the archive. So, unusual, yes, but apparently correct
